# Android RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo

Tags: android-intent, android-4.4-kitkat, android-cursor

So, After user picked contact I will be do following code to get number of contact:

```
public void openSmsWindowToContactNumber(Intent data, String smsBody) {

        // Get the URI that points to the selected contact
        Uri contactUri = data.getData();
        // We only need the NUMBER column, because there will be only one row in the result
        String[] projection = {Phone.NUMBER};

        // Perform the query on the contact to get the NUMBER column
        // We don't need a selection or sort order (there's only one result for the given URI)
        // CAUTION: The query() method should be called from a separate thread to avoid blocking
        // your app's UI thread. (For simplicity of the sample, this code doesn't do that.)
        // Consider using CursorLoader to perform the query.
        Cursor cursor = BaseActivity.this.getContentResolver()
                .query(contactUri, projection, null, null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int column = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
        String number = cursor.getString(column);

        Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("smsto:" + number));
        smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", smsBody);
        startActivity(smsIntent);
    }
```

When running on the device Lenovo A916 (A916) OS: Android 4.4 I get this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=75502, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.contacts/data/240 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.sm.proba/com.sm.proba.ClassPage}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3553)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3596)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1369)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at
```

cursor will be null, it is not found contact data. I started pick contact intent with following way:

```
Intent pickContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Uri.parse("content://contacts"));
pickContactIntent.setType(Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
startActivityForResult(pickContactIntent, REQUEST_CODE_PICK_CONTACTS);
```

Anybody know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Ever found a solution for this?

Comment: no i don't find solution

Comment: I suppose the cursor is wrong though, receiving phone number info is more complex as 2 cursors are required

Comment: Are you solve this problem?

Comment: Still looking for it, just had it yesterday. Will let you know if i can fix it. Normally i would think you don't have the permission in AndroidManifest.xml for READ_CONTACTS

Comment: I have read_contacts permission, I think problem another, when exists any contacts such as Google+ and etc.. And user select it and will be appear this error

Comment: I don't think that's a problem. My problem was solved just now after checking the AndroidManifest.xml in my apk. It had the targetsdkversion wrong because gradle changed it.

I changed the targetsdk version in gradle and it all works now. So check your AndroidManifest.xml in your apk to be sure about the permissions